# VB.net .. Error using objects?

Tags: vb.net

I get multiple errors in this section trying to figure out a computer win, user win or a tie. Can anyone please help edit my code? I have just hit the end of my abilities. I'm guessing I have to use objects? But I have been editing my code and it only gets worse from here. If anyone can help me I would be really thankful!!

```
' Card shuffling and dealing application.
Public Class DeckOfCardsTest
    Dim userwin As Integer
    Dim compwin As Integer
    Dim ties As Integer

    Private deck As New DeckOfCards() ' create the deck of cards

    ' shuffle the deck when user clicks the Shuffle Button
    Private Sub shuffleButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles shuffleButton.Click

        deck.Shuffle() ' shuffles the deck
        card1PictureBox.Image = Nothing ' clear image
        card2PictureBox.Image = Nothing ' clear image
        dealButton.Enabled = True ' allow user to click the Deal Button
        MessageBox.Show("Deck is shuffled")
    End Sub ' shuffleButton_Click

    Private Sub dealButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dealButton.Click

    End Sub ' dealButton_Click

    ' return an image for the Card argument
    Private Function GetCardImage(ByVal card As Card) As Image
        If card IsNot Nothing Then
            ' retrieve specific card image from resources
            Dim pictureResource = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(
              card.ToString().Replace(" ", ""))
            Return CType(pictureResource, Image) ' return Image
        Else
            dealButton.Enabled = False ' disable the Deal Button
            Return Nothing ' no more cards
        End If



    End Function ' GetCardImage
End Class ' DeckOfCardsTest
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about one particular problem, and trim the code down to the smallest amount that still exhibits the problem. Doing so may show you what the cause is.

Comment: Is `cardXPictureBox` derived from PictureBox control?

Comment: Generally where you have problems with code not making sense is where there is no comment. Is it safe to assume you wrote this portion of the code? Again, is this homework? No offense; we were all where you are at some point. Just tell us the assignment and maybe someone will be nice enough to lead you to a solution. But, man, if this is homework, this late in the semester... you should know your stuff by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that .FaceValue is not a property of a PictureBox.  You would instead need to grab the FaceValue from your Deck based upon the cards generated.

In response to your comment below, try something ***like*** this...

```
Dim card1 as new card = deck.DealCard()
card1PictureBox.Image = GetCardImage(card1)
```

So, that's how you set one of the PictureBoxes.  You can do the second one.  Then in your comparison to see who won...

```
if card1.FaceValue> card2.FaceValue then
    'blahblahblah
End if
```

Comment: You beat me to it. That is indeed the cause of the problems.

Comment: It would be sad if Joe spent all that time to create a StackOverflow account and paste walls of code despite the compiler telling him **'FaceValue' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'**.

Comment: @Dan Verdolino It is sad.. because no matter what I have tried to put in there.. I can't get it to work.

Comment: @APrough How do I do that though? I honestly have looked at example after example and I have no idea what I need to do.

Comment: See above to get you closer to the answer.  Note that there are better ways to do this process, but the above at least fits in with what you have.

Comment: @APrough  Thanks so much for looking into this. My programming knowledge isn't great, and as I said I have been stuck forever. I plugged in your code into the dealbutton (replacing the code there from before that we're correcting) and am getting errors. I posted a screenshot.. can you please help me? I'm not sure what else I can do. It's still not working.   https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/836/cardc.jpg

Comment: @John Willemse Any insight on the error?

Comment: @Joe,  I can't possibly write the whole program for you; I was trying to give you the direction to go in.  The idea is to create a variable that holds the Card object and then use those to compare.  I think you might have other errors in your code based upon the "End of Statement" error, but I can't tell from the screenshot.  It may help you to look at some simpler concepts than a card program until the concept of Classes is a little more clear.

Comment: @APrough I think I got it actually.. playing with a few things. Testing.. but thanks!